# Linear Regression : Can I use both levels and changes in the same model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, autoregressive

I have a linear model with 1 predictor variable in the form of:

$Y = a + b_{1}\times X$

Both $X$ and $Y$ are stationary variables and the fit of the model is good.
I have also created 2 other models based on the 3-month and 6-month % changes of the above variables, so I have another 2 models in the form of:

$ΔY_{3m} = a + b_{2} \times ΔX_{3m}$ and
$ΔY_{6m} = a + b_{3} \times ΔX_{6m}$

My question is: Does it make sense to have another model (as an improvement to my first one) in the form of:

$Y = a + b_{1} \times X + b_{2} \times ΔX_{3m} + b_{3} \times ΔX_{6m}$

to improve forecasts? But if yes, the question becomes:

1. What kind of model should I use (just a simple one like the above)?
2. How many lags should I use?
3. What are the potential econometric issues I may have with such a model?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your notation correctly it seems like you have a variable $ x $ which is measured at $t$ times.  You seem to be using $ \Delta$ to denote the difference between these times on the $x$ variable. By adding multiple predictors which are difference scores of the same variable, your model would suffer from having highly correlated predictors, this is called high multicollinearity. It is assumed that your predictors are not highly correlated, therefore you may suffer other violations regarding your residuals, like normality and constant variance assumptions.

1. I would recommend a model which accounts for repeated measures, I would reshape your data to "long" format, adding a categorical time variable (T1, T2, T3). Then specify a model such that the error term accounts for the repeated measurements. Something like this:

$$ Y_i = a + b_1x + b_2t + b_3(x*t) + \epsilon_i$$

Where $x$ is your predictor variable, and $t$ is your time variable which is a categorical index of when the measurement occurred. $\epsilon_i$ represents the error term which accounts for the fact that cases were measures multiple times, the $i$ subscript denotes this.

2. Using this model no lags are necessary as the variable is expressed as an interaction with time.
3. This model will not suffer the issues of multi-colinearity, it will have more power, and a lower error rate.

I dont know what language you use, but in R I would specify this model with the lme4 library like so:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

lmer(Y ~ x + t + x:t + (1|ID))
```

Where ID is the variable which denotes which observation is which.

Comment: "The model assumes this is not the case" ?

Comment: I could have been more clear, an assumption of multiple linear regression is that the predictors in the model are not highly correlated. This assumption is sometimes left out in texts, but is an important diagnostic to assess.

Comment: @Roman_Numerals thanks. This is what I want to achieve. Let's assume that Y are product quantities bought for a certain price (i.e. X). If for some reason in one of the quarters the quantities bought move much higher than what the change in the price would imply and the next quarter much lower then the 2 quarters would show an "overreaction" vs. the quarterly changes in the price. However the 6m changes would show changes in line (2nd quarter would be a payback to the 1st). I am trying to include the 6m changes (or other horizon) to mitigate the effect of overreaction shown overall. Any ideas?

Comment: What I am hearing is that you anticipate a nonlinear effect of x across time, in that each measurement will not be concurrently larger (or smaller) than the last. The model I specify above can treat time (t) as a dummy coded variable. In this model there would be 2 coefficients in the interaction term. Each would be a comparison of the slope of the dummy coded time variable to the reference time. For example a slope for 3 months (Time 2) of 3.8, would represent a slope of x with y that is 3.8 units greater than that of the reference category (Time 1) of X with Y.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if I create separate univariate models based on the levels and the changes and then aggregate the forecasts based on some kind of model averaging technique?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "better". Multiple models with an averaging approach would be less parsimonious than the model I provide, which leads to less certainty in the predictions. However, the final model you suggest in your question would likely be biased due to the high correlation in the predictors, this would lead to less accurate predictions.

Comment: Hi: I'm from time-series background and I don't know if this is a time series framework ( sounds possible but I couldn't tell for sure ) but having changes and levels on one side with just the level on the other side is not done in time series problems. I'm not sure of the theoretical reason for that but I know it's not done.  If you think that the level in y and a change in level of y depends on the level of x and change in the level of x, then check out the whole notion of 2 series being "co-integrated". In that framework, you can incorporate the level of y and the change in the level of y.